# Update Active Directory "mail" attribute via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to update the email address listed in AD for all the users in a particular OU. This is the powershell script I'm using, but it's not working properly

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=OtherOU,OU=SomeOu,DC=Domain,DC=local" | Set-ADUser -email $_.samaccountname@domain.com
```

I think it's because $_.samaccountname isn't returning anything when I try to do Set-ADUser.
Can anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the current context $_ is null. You need to use Foreach-Object in order for $_ to be available.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * ... | Foreach-Object{
   Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -Email "$($_.samaccountname)@domain.com"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a csv file with SamAccountName & email address

```
"SamAccountName","EmailAddress"
"john","john@xyz.com"
```

step 1: import to a variable

```
$users = Import-Csv .\email.csv
```

step 2:  Call the variable

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName -EmailAddress $user.EmailAddress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll need to use a subexpression for that:

```
"$($_.samaccountname)@domain.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming username is domain\user1 or user1@domain.com

```
$user = "user1"
Set-ADUser $user -emailaddress "firtname.lastname@xyz.com"
Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Properties emailaddress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase "OU=OUName,DC=domain,DC=com" |  
  Foreach-Object { Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -Email "$($_.samaccountname)@domain.com" }
```

This is from:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33311.powershell-update-mail-and-mailnickname-for-all-users-in-ou.aspx